# New window Drag&Drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, target

So if i have this http://jsfiddle.net/sPbmM/93/ how can i open in a new window?

```
$('.drag').draggable({
                revert: "invalid",
                helper: "clone"

            });
$('.cart ').droppable({
       accept: ".drag",

    drop: function(event, ui){       
        window.location=$(ui.draggable).find("a.addtocart").attr("href");
    }
});
```

I've tried with `window.open` and also `.attr("href","target","_blank")` but i think the sintaxis is not correct
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i use `window.open=...`

```
window.open($(ui.draggable).find("a.addtocart").attr("href"));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sPbmM/108/)